# Phonegap camera and capture restart app

Tags: android, cordova

I am implementing a photo upload feature in my application,
user can upload a photo in two different ways, using the camera or photo album.

Main problem is when I open the camera or photo album the app is restarted.
I used different foreground camera plugins but problem is not solved.

When the camera or album opens, the app automatically pause and resume,
I'm already using resume event in my app, when app resumes opens the home page.

I need, after finishing image upload, to go to the previous page and not open the home page.
I'm using cordova 3.6.4 version.

```
function captureImage() {
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1                    
});
    //window.history.back();
}
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        //alert("###1");
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }
}
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        //alert("###2");
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;
                //alert("image path "+path);


       ft.upload(path,
            "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
            function(result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("image upload failed");
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code (not mine) and it works well for capture photo and it doesn't restart the app :

```
function capturePhoto(){
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,null,{sourceType:1,quality:60});
}


function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
// Get image handle
//
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('cameraPic');
// Unhide image elements
//
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
// Show the captured photo
// The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
//
    smallImage.src =imageData;

}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
// Get image handle
    console.log(JSON.stringify(imageData));
// Get image handle
//
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('cameraPic');
// Unhide image elements
//
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
// Show the captured photo
// The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
//
    smallImage.src = imageData;
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
// Uncomment to view the image file URI
// console.log(imageURI);
// Get image handle
//
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('cameraPic');
// Unhide image elements
//
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
// Show the captured photo
// The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
//
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function

function capturePhotoWithData() {
// Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 30, correctOrientation: true });
}

function capturePhotoWithFile() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoFileSuccess, onFail, { quality:50,  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,     correctOrientation: true });
}

// A button will call this function

function getPhoto(source) {
// Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 30,destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        correctOrientation: true });
}
// Called if something bad happens.
//
function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var pictureSource;   // picture source
  var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
  pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
  destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;

$(document).on('click','.capture_photo',function(){
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
              quality : 75,
              destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
              sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
              // allowEdit : true,
              encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
              // targetWidth: 100,
              // targetHeight: 100,
              popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
              saveToPhotoAlbum: false 
            });
        }); 


        function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) { 
          sessionStorage.setItem("img_api",imageData);
          $('#captureimg').attr('src','data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
        }

        $(document).on('click','.select_gallery',function(){
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM });
        });

        function onFail(message) {
           alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
```

Hope, it will helpful